# Iterating a PCollection for every element in another PCollection in Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have 2 PCollections, A and B.

I would like to do something like that:

```
for a in A:
   for b in B:
      a.give(b);
```

B contains all lines from a 10GB file.

I thought about having each worker read the file himself using java code and write to to its own disk, but I would like to use beam framework functionality as much as possible, so that option is a last resort for now.

Is what im trying to do possible in beam?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple ways to do something this. Whichever approach you can choose depends on the specifics/details of your problem:

- use side-inputs. Basically you are loading a `B` file into the memory and then can access it for each `A` element. [Link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs). You probably still need to implement some file loading and element lookup logic;
- join `A` and `B` using `CoGroupByKey` ([link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey)) or a `Join` library ([link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-extensions/#join-library));
- as you mentioned, managing the file manually is not a bad option if nothing else works well;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isnt it a bit big for a side input? would incurr a lot of network IO between the workers no?
CoGroupBy and Join force me to "artificially" create a cartesian product between the collections, which will create a very big collection (which might not be a problem) but I was hoping there is support for this using beam and I wont have to use this type of "workarounds"